# Swift/CoreData - Variable reference changes after initializing

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios9

I'm getting my feet wet with CoreData using Swift and coming across something that doesn't make sense to me.

Basically I'm building a simple map app where a user can drop a pin, select the info button from the annotation view, and add that location to a "Favorites" list. I want to keep that list between sessions.

I have this in my AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.dataController = DataController()

    return true
}
```

DataController() is where the code is located that deals with....you guessed it. The data. I only have an init() and one other function that adds data.

This is the code that takes the info and uses a function in the DataController class to add that data to my data set

```
let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            appDelegate.dataController.addItemToData(self.locationInfo.address, city: self.locationInfo.city, zip: self.locationInfo.zip, country: self.locationInfo.country, latitude: self.locationInfo.lat, longitude: self.locationInfo.long)
        })
```

This is where it gets weird. This screenshot is when the app is on "let appDelegate =...."

[appDelegate initialization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1me2.png)

And this is when the app is running the next line down

[appDelegate.dataController....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA6QE.png)

As you can see from the images, dataController has a value at first, but when I try to use it one line down it equals nil and the appDelegate also has a different value. The app also errors out with "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" because of that. Has anyone else seen something like this or know what may be going on?

Comment: how is your `dataController` property declared in your AppDelegate class?

Comment: @Paulw11 `var dataController: DataController!`

Comment: If the first screenshot is when the debugger is actually pointing at the `let appDelegate=...` then at that point the `appDelegate` variable in the debugger isn't valid and the values of its properties are not valid either.  On the next line `appDelegate` has actually been assigned to your app delegate instance (you can see that the address has changed, it ends in c70 not c20), so your `dataController` property isn't initialised.  The debugger points at the line that will be executed when you step, not the line that was executed